# Label rows of unique combinations on two parameters in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, label, unique, multiple-columns

In a data.frame containing information on two parameters (date and station), I would like to label
each unique combination of the two in a new column.

What I have:

```
df
       date station  
1    april     GF3   
2 december     GF1    
3    april     GF2   
4    april     GF3     
5 december     GF1
```

What I want:

```
df2
       date station   Label
1    april     GF3      1
2 december     GF1      2 
3    april     GF2      3
4    april     GF3      1  
5 december     GF1      2
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please make it easier for others to get your data. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/6607497

Answer (score 1):

Paste the values together and use `match` + `unique` to create unique group number.

```
vals <- paste(df$date, df$station)
df$label <- match(vals, unique(vals))

#      date station label
#1    april     GF3     1
#2 december     GF1     2
#3    april     GF2     3
#4    april     GF3     1
#5 december     GF1     2
```

If the numbering of `label` is not important you can also use `cur_group_id()` in `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(date, station) %>% mutate(label = cur_group_id()) %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dense_rank` will also do

```
df %>% mutate(Label = dense_rank(paste(date, station)))

      date station Label
1    april     GF3     2
2 december     GF1     3
3    april     GF2     1
4    april     GF3     2
5 december     GF1     3
```

It will however, give preference to number alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

A `dplyr` approach with a `left_join`:

```
d <- tribble(~date, ~station,
             "april","GF3",
             "december","GF1",    
             "april","GF2",   
             "april","GF3", 
             "december","GF1")

d %>% left_join(
  d %>% distinct(date, station) %>% 
    rowid_to_column(),
  by = c("station", "date")
)
```

Which results in:

```
  date     station rowid
  <chr>    <chr>   <int>
1 april    GF3         1
2 december GF1         2
3 april    GF2         3
4 april    GF3         1
5 december GF1         2
```